# Should I Play the Previous Halo's before Halo 5?

Tags: halo-5-guardians, halo-series

I have always wanted to play Halo for a long time and I was so happy that they finally gave it a T rating.

So I might buy Halo 5 because it just came out + it got  rated T.

My dad wont let me buy the other Halo's because they are rated M.

Do I need to play the previous Halos to be able to understand/play this one?

Comment: I would recommend it. One of the things people criticized Halo 5 for doing is not fully explaining the backstory of a certain character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Halo 1-3,ODST and kind of Reach are of a different saga, so although important to the whole series, not as important to the current "Reclaimer Saga" which began with Halo 4.

Although it's highly recommended that you play the previous games, especially 4. The Halo Universe is much bigger than just the games, and you can get a much better understanding of the happenings in Halo 5 by reading the [books](https://www.google.com/search?q=halo+lore&oq=halo+lore&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.4111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=halo+books), watching the [movies](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-sg/halo-channel/shows/halo-nightfall/season-1), and other media on [Waypoint](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/universe).

The easiest and shortest method would be to get the Master Chief Collection, as it contains all games that matter, as well as additional lore to help, but if M rated games are banned for you, you will probably be ok just exploring the [wikia](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Halo_Universe) and the many [imgur albums](https://imgur.com/gallery/bI6Ih) that explain the lore quickly and deeply (just not as fun as actually playing it...).

Comment: Wait... You said that Halo 4 is more important than Halo 1-3 and ODST. Would you recommend http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2262308/?ref_=tt_rec_tt ?